# Why to rescale images in deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

When using `ImageDataGenerator` in Keras, should I rescale the images?

why to use `rescale`?

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually done for practical considerations. Standardizing input to lie within `[0, 1]` range helps gradient descent based optimizations to converge faster i.e., it speeds up the training. It can also sometimes help you find better local optima i.e., improve model performance.